# Dictation always quits after about ten seconds no matter what I do

Tags: voice-dictation

I like dictation but after I turn it on in, say, Text-Edit, it records for about ten seconds, then I get the three dots instead of the Microphone icon. Here, I'll see if I can dictate right here, and we'll see how long it will last:

I just used the double command key to initiate the dictation and I'm talking in a normal rate of speed and I have not done main line breaks or anything and I am just waiting for the microphone icon to turn

That's it. It started recording after "I just used . . ." and ended after " . . . icon to turn"

It does this without fail no matter what program I'm in. Since there's no option for an external microphone I just got as close to the computer as possible wondering if it had lost my voice somehow and thence stopped recurring, but this doesn't seem to be the case. Anyone know anything about this? I can't find the issue mentioned elsewhere.

Comment: Are there any log messages related to it in Console.app? Including them here could make the question more searchable.

Comment: Since it uses Internet, how is your Internet connection ? Does something like Skype works well ?